# Two-step Engle and Granger's procedure

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, cointegration

If I want to check if there is cointegration between $X_t$ and $Y_t$ in the following model, is it enough to check p-value of Breusch-Godfrey test? The maintained hypothesis in this test is no cointegration, so **is finding a significant p-value enough**? And why are there two equations for the first diff?

\begin{align}
y_t &= -0,03+\underset{(0,01)}{0,12}X_t+U_t \\[5 pt]
\Delta U_t &= -0,01-\underset{(0,38)}{0,95}U_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t &p(BG)=0,005 \\[5 pt]
\Delta U_t &= -0,01-\underset{(0,03)}{0,97}U_{t-1}+\underset{(0,02)}{0,09}\Delta U_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t &p(BG)=0,882 \\[5 pt]
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Breusch-Godfrey test is a test for serial correlation. Since the $p$-value in the first regression for $\Delta U_t$ is small, I assume that however showed you this output wanted to control for the apparent serial correlation via adding $\Delta U_{t-1}$, which apparently worked, given the larger $p$-value in the second regression.

Whether or not there is cointegration according to the Engle-Granger procedure is something you determine by comparing the t-ratio on $U_{t-1}$ against the appropriate critical values of the Engle-Granger distribution.

Comment: So the appropriate t-ratio is that from the second equation - $-0,97/0,03$? And, in general, I use the t-ratio from the equation with the higher p-value?

Comment: (1) Yes. I find it surprising, though, that the s.e. has decreased by a full order of magnitude between the two regressions, though - are these numbers made up? (2) You should have a test regression that you can trust is well-specified. It is not true that the higher the p-value the better, but it is good (or common practice) to say that the test regression has "passed" that particular test.

Comment: Yes, these numbers are made up for the purpose of exercise.